Heating kitchen with gas oven
I don’t understand why it is dangerous (carbon monoxide) to heat my kitchen with the gas oven, door open, but it is not dangerous if the oven door is closed.

I assume there is some ventilation on the back. For sure it need gas, but also oxygen (but so also to remove air). By opening the oven you may disrupt the intended flow. -- Also consider the time you use the oven vs. using as heater. Oven: I think 2 hours maximum and in such long case also at low power.

Ovens will turn on and off in an attempt to maintain a certain temperature. When the oven door is closed, there is a finite amount of space inside that needs to be heated.
If the door is left open, the oven will continue burning gas in an attempt to bring the whole room up to the temperature the thermostat is expecting.
Since this is unlikely to happen with even the smallest, best insulated kitchen, you'll end up constantly burning a considerable amount of gas, resulting in a much higher concentration of carbon monoxide.

Gas ovens are not designed to be room heaters and do not have safety features that room heaters have. The gas burners are not designed to be continually operated for prolonged periods of time. Also, with the oven door open continually there is nothing preventing something from inadvertently entering the oven which could result in a significant fire. if unattended, such a situation could be disastrous.
